# Sorting value fetched by jquery ajax call into javascript multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays

I'd like to store a value that is correctly fetched via (NON ASYNC) ajax call (from facebook graph api) back to my javascript multidimensional array.

Everything works fine until the part when the data that I get from facebook api has to be stored to my previously defined 2d-array (and afterwards printed on the page via jquery append). I simply can't figure out where's the problem.

Here's the code sample:

**Defining 2d array and its values:**

```
fbpages = new Array (13);
i=0;
for (i=0;i<=12;i++) fbpages[i]=new Array(4);

fbpages[0][0] = "http://graph.facebook.com/120830347930692?callback=?"; 
fbpages[0][1] = "Kupi";
fbpages[0][2] = "/vijesti/tag/kupi/";
fbpages[0][3] = 0;

fbpages[1][0] = "http://graph.facebook.com/214014840762?callback=?";
fbpages[1][1] = "Kolek";
fbpages[1][2] = "/vijesti/tag/kolek/";
fbpages[1][3] = 0;
```

etc...

**Fetch the data for every page using the URL from the array fbpages[x][0] and store it back to the same array, to the field fbpages[x][3]:**

```
y=0;
for (y=0;y<=12;y++){
    pageURL = fbpages[y][0];
    fetchData(y,pageURL);
};

function fetchData (index,fbpageurl) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: fbpageurl,
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            success:function(data){fbpages[index][3]=data.likes;}
        });
};
```

Data printing works fine.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm confused about the actual problem if the data printing works fine.  Looking at your code, it should work correctly.

Comment: I'm with @dmcnelis but you could try to refactor and simplify your loops to reduce the possibility for errors. E.g. `for (var y=0;y<=12;y++)` will do fine, no need to set `y` to `0` before starting the loop while defining the variable using `var` is highly recommended. Also, I'd recommend using `push` instead of defining the length of the arrays before filling them. Like this you can avoid empty elements in case something goes wrong.

Comment: data printing is ok but the problem is that it prints out 0 (from the fbpages[someindex][3])  instead of the new value I get from ajax call (data.likes). So it obviously means that the data I got is not stored back to that array (but it is fetched correctly since on alert it prints correct values).